# Can anyone help me in defining nonlinear spring element in ABAQUS?

Tags: abaqus

I am trying to define a non-linear spring element in Abaqus using the following values.
-8505.0193, -40
-6854, -30
-5514.401, -20
-4075.366, -10
0, 0
4075.366, 10
5514.401, 20
6854, 30
8505.0193, 40.

It is working fine with positive values. But when I define zero or negative values. it is showing an error as
"The independent variables must be arranged in ascending order. This error may have been caused by a possible empty line on the datacards in the property definition."

Comment: Hi, can you provide the snippet of your code regarding the spring behaviour definition?